# How do I configure Asterisk to use G729 on a trunk with FreePBX

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I've successfully got the channel from phone->PBX working on G279. I'm just trying to get the PBX->trunk to also be G279.

I did this by using FreePBX and putting in allow=g729,ulaw into each extension. As I'm using FreePBX and no asterisk expert I wanted to avoid editing sip.conf if possible.

The question is, how can get the same effect for the trunk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have g729 codec module at this point.

In your trunk configuration page,  in PEER Details fields

add

disallow=all

allow=g729

Make sure you do it in the same sequence as above.  Also do the same in USER Details if you have any entry in this field.

Comment: worked perfectly, call quality restored, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to do this now.  Navigate the "Asterisk SIP Settings" page and simply tick the codec.  You can also use this page to change the priority of the authorized codecs...

```
http://pbx.yourdomain.com/admin/config.php?display=sipsettings
```